# Merge hashes that have the same description field, summing the other fields

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes of form:

```
{ description: 'string', b: float, c: float }
```

I need to get an array of merged hashes so that if hashes have same value at key `description` sum values of `b` and `c`, (of course keeping value of `a` unaltered), otherwise (if value of `description` is unique) just add hash to array.

Current solution:

```
array_of_hashes.inject([]) do |lines, line|
  if lines.none? { |l| l[:description] == line[:description] }
    lines << line
  else
    lines
      .find { |l| l[:description] == line[:description] }
      .merge!(line) { |key, old_v, new_v| key == :description ? old_v : old_v + new_v }
    lines
  end
end
```

I am 100% sure there's a nicer solution.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the code being a little more complex than it needs to be, I see two issues:

- a performance problem: the `.find { |l| l[:description] == line[:description] }` is called for each element in the array of hashes, leading to an O(n^2) time algorithm (because the array lookup takes linear time)
- a more subtle thing: the initial hashes are mutated by your code. When you do `old_v + new_v` that modifies the very hashes that have been provided as an input to your function/code. This might not be a problem for you, but I think it's good practice to avoid mutability where possible.

To solve these things, let's use a hash of hashes. We'll have a hash that has the `:description` values as key (thus allowing to look things up in constant time) and a hash containing the values to be cummulated.

Also, to save the verification of whether a certain key already exists or not, I will use [the `new {|hash, key| block }` syntax](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) when creating the outside hash.

Here's the code:

```
results = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {b: 0, c: 0} }
array_of_hashes.each do |h|
  cummulative_hash = results[h[:description]]
  cummulative_hash[:b] += h[:b]
  cummulative_hash[:c] += h[:c]
end
```

At this point, `results` looks like this:

```
{"string"=>{:b=>3, :c=>6}, "other_string"=>{:b=>1, :c=>2}}
```

This can be easily converted to your array format, like this:

```
results.map{|k, v| {description: k}.merge v}

=> [{:description=>"string", :b=>3, :c=>6},
    {:description=>"other_string", :b=>1, :c=>2}]
```

---

In the example above I hardcoded the `:b` and `:c` keys.
For a more generic treatment of the keys to be cummulated, here's the (slightly adjusted) code:

```
results = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }
array_of_hashes.each do |h|
  cummulative = results[h[:description]]
  h.each do |k, v|
    cummulative[k] = (cummulative[k] || 0) + h[k] if k != :description
  end
end
results.map{|k, v| {description: k}.merge v}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer! `cummulative_hash = results[h[:description]]` is an awesome thing as well as default proc. My concern here is that I would like to get it done within single cycle of iteration, and both of solution you've provided suggest 2 iterations.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Is it absolutely necessary that the output is an array? If so, I don't know how you can do it in less than two iterations with reasonable performance. If, however, it's acceptable to output a hash, then just use the code without the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enumerable#group_by` to divide the array_of_hashes into groups by description.  Then replace each group with a single hash that contains the sum.

```
array_of_hashes = [
  {description: 'small', a: 1, b: 0.2, c: 0.3},
  {description: 'large', a: 100, b: 200, c: 300},
  {description: 'small', a: 4, b: 0.5, c: 0.6},
  {description: 'large', a: 400, b: 500, c: 600},
  {description: 'unique', a: 'hi', b: true, c: false},
]

answer = array_of_hashes.group_by {|h| h[:description]}.values
answer.map! {|first, *rest|
  if rest.empty?
    first
  else
    first.dup.tap {|sum|
      rest.each {|h| sum[:b] += h[:b]; sum[:c] += h[:c]}}
  end
}

require 'pp'
pp answer
```

Output is

```
[{:description=>"small", :a=>1, :b=>0.7, :c=>0.8999999999999999},
 {:description=>"large", :a=>100, :b=>700, :c=>900},
 {:description=>"unique", :a=>"hi", :b=>true, :c=>false}]
```

In this code, if a group has only one hash (with a unique description), we just add hash to answer without duplicating the hash or doing sums (`0 + true` would fail).  If a group has more than one hash, we put the sums in a duplicate of the first hash.  Unfortunately, the answer doesn't preserve the values of `a: 4` and `a: 400`.